# Cypher: Find relationships of nodes with connected parents

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm hoping this diagram will be sufficient to explain what I'm after:

```
                   true
          a--------------------b
          |                    |
   parent |                    | parent
          |                    |
         a_e------------------b_e
               experimental
```

nodes a_e and b_e are experimental observations that each have only one parent, a and b, respectively. I know a true relationship exists between a and b, and I want to find cases where experimental relationships were observed between a_e and b_e. Among other things, I tried the following:

```
 MATCH (n)-[:true]-(m)
 WITH n,m
 MATCH (n)-[:parent]-(i)
 MATCH (m)-[:parent]-(j)
 WITH i,j
 OPTIONAL MATCH (i)-[r]-(j)
 RETURN r
```

but this returns no rows. I'm thinking of this like a nested loop, matching all possible relationships between all i's and all j's. Is this type of query possible?

Comment: The query seems to be working actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
match (n)-[:true]-(m) 
match (n)-[:parent]->(n_child)-[:experimental]-(m_child)<-[:PARENT]-(m) 
return  n_child,m_child
```

(not tested)

Assuming this is an example and you have labels etc. on your nodes.

Comment: Yes, this works for the example I gave above and is the compact syntax I was looking for. This indicates that my problem is with the assumptions I'm making about relationships present in my data, and not with Cypher.